# Does ROS currently install on Mint 13?

Tags: ros, rosdep, debian, linuxmint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ROS on a fresh Mint 13 install, and after following the [debian install guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Debian), I get stuck at step 1.5.

Rosdep -a gives the following output:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py",
> ```
>
> line 111, in rosdep_main
> exit_code = _rosdep_main(args)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py",
> line 232, in _rosdep_main
> return _package_args_handler(command, parser, options, args)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py",
> line 255, in _package_args_handler
> lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(options)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py",
> line 102, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
> verbose=options.verbose)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py",
> line 477, in create_default
> matcher = DataSourceMatcher.create_default(os_override=os_override)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py",
> line 228, in create_default
> os_name, os_version, os_codename = os_detect.detect_os()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/os_detect.py",
> line 404, in detect_os
> raise OsNotDetected("Could not detect OS, tried %s"%attempted)
> OsNotDetected: Could not detect OS, tried ['ubuntu', 'rhel', 'osx',
> 'opensuse', 'mint', 'gentoo',
> 'freebsd', 'fedora', 'debian',
> 'cygwin', 'arch']

I've tried running rosdep install -a --os=mint:maya, but here's a sample of what I get in return:

> ```
> ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their
> ```
>
> rosdep keys resolved
> to system dependencies:
> rosconsole: Unsupported OS [mint]
> image_view: Unsupported OS [mint]
> carrot_planner: Missing resource pcl
> ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
> ROS path [1]=/home/nick/ros/navigation
> ROS path [2]=/home/nick/ros/diagnostics

Along with a ton more "Unsupported OS [mint]" issues. My question is: does a workaround exist, or can I simply not install ROS on my Mint 13 system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45563/does-ros-currently-install-on-mint-13?/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the first error, there might be a bug in rospkg. You might want to file a ticket on it here: https://github.com/ros/rospkg/issues

For the second, it looks like there are only a few packages that are missing dependencies. You can try adding the appropriate deps and testing it out  / contributing it via these instructions: http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/contributing_rules.html

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a workaround you can set your os to the corresponding ubuntu version as Mint is very closely related to ubuntu.  I'm not sure which codename maya maps to but do something like this: --os=ubuntu:precise

---

Originally posted by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) with karma: 1145 on 2012-10-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pvfjr1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7276/pvfjr1/) on 2013-09-30**:
Changing the OS as Tully suggested seems to be working for me at the moment.